# how to create a dropdown with iOSDropDown Pod with correct layout measurements

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Layout is the main problem , because i create it but on clicking dropdown the list comes behind the other buttons, so how to change it to correct.

Comment: Do not hesitate to add your code using which you want to achieve correct layout.

Comment: Try to use through this link best and simple dropdown https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here Is your view is above from all buttons.

[image]